# Android camera preview with buffer to MediaCodec and MediaMuxer add timestamp overlay

Tags: android, opencv, android-camera, android-mediacodec

I want to record camera's preview byte[] by using MediaCodec and MediaMuxer.

The code segment is in CameraPreviewCallback.

```
@Override
public void onPreviewFrame(byte[] data, Camera camera) {

    // before pass byte[] data to encoder, draw a datetime string into data.
    drawDatetimeOverlay(data);

    // pass data to encoder, that has the MediaMuxer to implement store frames to a mp4 file.
    mp4Encoder.encodeFrame(data);

    camera.addCallbackBuffer(data);
}
```

And I want to know how to implement the function of **drawDatetimeOverlay(byte[] data)**, Pass a frame data then draw text on it.

Comment: You can start with **javacv** `cvPutText` class.